# C# Enable/disable Windows 7 / Windows 7 Embedded Firewall

Tags: c#, windows, range, firewall, argumentexception

I am working on a project where it must be possible to enable/disable the integrated Windows Firewall of a Windows 7 Embedded system by programm.

using the code:

```
private static INetFwPolicy2 getCurrPolicy()
    {
        INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2;
        Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
        if (tNetFwPolicy2 != null)
            fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
        else
            return null;
        return fwPolicy2;
    }

    public static bool GetFirewallStatus()
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = getCurrPolicy();
            NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_ fwCurrentProfileTypes;
            //read Current Profile Types (only to increase Performace)
            //avoids access on CurrentProfileTypes from each Property
            fwCurrentProfileTypes = NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_)fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
            result = (fwPolicy2.get_FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void SetFirewallStatus(bool newStatus)
    {
        try
        {
            NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_ fwCurrentProfileTypes;
            INetFwPolicy2 currPolicy = getCurrPolicy();
            //read Current Profile Types (only to increase Performace)
            //avoids access on CurrentProfileTypes from each Property
            fwCurrentProfileTypes = NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_)currPolicy.CurrentProfileTypes;
            currPolicy.set_FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes, newStatus);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

What happens is that at every function call of the currPolicy objects i get the following message:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Now there is my question: Why do I get this error and how can I make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just stop and disable the firewall service programmatically?

Comment: Well, allready thought of that, too. Might be a possibility. But if there is a API giving me an opportunity to set Firewall settings by it, I consider using it.
Since it doesn't work I wanted to know if anyone else got problems like mine, too.

Comment: Anyways if there is no way to make it work, my next try will be using the commandline tool
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766337%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Fair point. That TechNet post looks more promising.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to solve the problem using the API.
Anyways, setting the firewall on or off can be acheived by using the link in my previous comment using the commandline tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the documentation again, i came across the line
"When you pass a profile type obtained from the CurrentProfileTypes property, make sure that you pass only one profile type to get_FirewallEnabled and put_FirewallEnabled. Note that get_CurrentProfileTypes can return multiple profiles."

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And yes, i have actually got more than one profile type returned.
So the API works when you only pass one profile to the get and set methods of FirewallEnabled.
e.g.:

```
result = (fwPolicy2.get_FirewallEnabled(NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC));
```